# How to interpret the code: module_invoke_all('user', 'logout', NULL, $user);?

Tags: users

How to interpret this line of code?

```
module_invoke_all('user', 'logout', NULL, $user);
```

Obviously, it logs out the current user, but how do the four arguments make it happen?

I read through the doc, but I can't find information about the four parameters.

Can anyone explain?

> From Documentation:
> [`module_invoke_all()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7)
>
> Invoke a hook in all enabled modules that implement it.
>
> Parameters
> $hook The name of the hook to invoke.
> ... Arguments to pass to the hook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they don't log the user out. That is done by the call to `session_destroy()` in [user_logout()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7).

That line only invokes the hook to tell other modules *that* the user was just logged out so they can react based on that.

The passed arguments are simply those that match the executed hook. Note that the Drupal 7 version is different from what you posted above, which is the Drupal 6 version.